# Simplifying a summation ratio

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, summation-method

I need some help to simplify the following:
$$\frac{\sum_{k=0}^na_nr^n}{\sum_{k=0}^na_n(1+r)^n},$$
where $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $a_n$>0 and $r$>0.

More specifically, the question I have is 
$$\frac{\sum _{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{\Gamma(n+k)}{\Gamma(n-k)k!}\gamma ^{n-k}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^k}{\sum _{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{\Gamma(n+k)}{\Gamma(n-k)k!}(1+\gamma)^{n-k}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^k}.$$

Is there any other way to write into another form? Any suggestion and reference are welcome.

Comment: Without any information about the $a_n$, what could we do ?

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite $$\sum _{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{\Gamma(n+k)}{\Gamma(n-k)\,k!}\gamma ^{n-k}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^k=\gamma^n\sum _{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{\Gamma(n+k)}{\Gamma(n-k)\,k!}\left(\frac{1}{2\gamma}\right)^k=\gamma^n\sqrt{\frac{2\gamma}{\pi }}\, e^{\gamma }\,  K_{\frac{1}{2}-n}(\gamma )$$ where appears the modified Bessel function of the second kind.

Just do the same for the denominator to get
$$\frac{\sum _{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{\Gamma(n+k)}{\Gamma(n-k)k!}\gamma ^{n-k}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^k}{\sum _{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{\Gamma(n+k)}{\Gamma(n-k)k!}(1+\gamma)^{n-k}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^k}=\frac 1e\left(\frac{\gamma}{1+\gamma}\right)^{n+\frac 12}\frac{K_{\frac{1}{2}-n}(\gamma )}{K_{\frac{1}{2}-n}(\gamma +1)}$$

Comment: Thanks for this . I noticed the relationship between this finite summation and the Bessel polynomial. But could we simplify it further more.

Comment: @gouwangzhangdong. I don't think so without more information about the possible values of $\gamma$.

Comment: The only requirement on the $\gamma$ is greater than 0. What kind of values of $\gamma$ could simply the expression then? I still cannot see it.

Comment: @gouwangzhangdong. I suppose that for small values or infinitely large values of $\gamma$, we could build some asymptotics.